# Return value from PHP to JS via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What am I doing wrong? AJAX success appears not to be receiving anything at all as none of the three alerts are shown. The process works, except I do not get any response

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/charge.php',
  data: {
    tokenid: token.id,
    email: customer_email,
    amount: amount,
    description: customer_first_name + ' ' + customer_surname + ' | ' + reference
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);

    if (response == "OK") {
      alert('Payment successfully made! ');
    } else {
      alert('Payment could not be processed. Please try again.');
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

```php
<?php
  require_once('./stripe/config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['tokenid'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $amount = $_POST['amount'] ;
  $description = $_POST['description'] ;

  $err = 'OK' ;

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  try { 
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'GBP',
      'description' => $description
    ));
  } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $err = "Declined - $e";
  }

  function response() {
    global $err;
    print $err ;
    return $err;
  }
  exit response() ;
?>
```

Please help as this is driving me mad.

Comment: Check the console of the Browser, do you see any JavaScript error?

Comment: Try using `return response();` instead of `exit response() ;`

Comment: you have specified that php will return json you are not returning any json from php that is why it is having error. return json from php then it is ok. to check this add `,
        error: function (data) {
           
        }` and check if it goes there

Answer (score 0):

Remove the response function, do a print of the errors

```
 <?php
  require_once('./stripe/config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['tokenid'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $amount = $_POST['amount'] ;
  $description = $_POST['description'] ;

  $err = 'OK' ;

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token
  ));

 try { $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'GBP',
      'description' => $description
  ));
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    $err = "Declined - $e";
    }
echo $err;
?>
```

set the dataType to text `dataType: 'text',`

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery AJAX request is setup to receive JSON (through the `dataType` property), yet you are returning a string. That string is also repeated several times, and the `response()` function is pretty redundant.

To fix this, amend your PHP code to actually return JSON, and your jQuery code to read that JSON properly. Try this:

```php
$success = true;
$err = '';

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => $email,
  'source'  => $token
));

try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => $amount,
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'description' => $description
  ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  $success = false;
  $err = "Declined - $e";
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'err' => $err));
```

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/charge.php',
  data: {
    tokenid: token.id,
    email: customer_email,
    amount: amount,
    description: customer_first_name + ' ' + customer_surname + ' | ' + reference
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
      alert('Payment successfully made! ');
    } else {
      console.log(response.err);
      alert('Payment could not be processed. Please try again.');
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```